# Reading wrong unsigned long value in Arduino ethernet server client

Tags: arduino, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I am getting just the half of the value when I try to read an `unsigned long` value using Arduino ethernet. The hex value should be `0x98765432` but the result is `0x5432`. What am I doing wrong?

```c
unsigned char bufArr [4];

for void loop() {
    EthernetClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
        Serial.println("new client");
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {
                //read 4 bytes
                client.read(bufArr,4);
                //use shift to convert it to a unsigned long
                unsigned long irCmd = bufArr[3]<<24|bufArr[2]<<16|bufArr[1]<<8|bufArr[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I get that you are getting this hex file using this line of code:

unsigned long irCmd = bufArr[3]<<24|bufArr[2]<<16|bufArr[1]<<8|bufArr[0];

Now the thing isyou are using bufArr[3] to bufArr[0] which means you are reading total 4 values from 3 to 0 thats why you are getting just 4 values, read from bufArr[7] and you will get all the 8 values.

Comment: My understanding is that the number 0x98765432 requires 4 bytes: 98, 76, 54 and 32. I am reading the same way following number: 0x2002:

Comment: and did read them with client.read(bufArr,2); word irAddr = bufArr[1]<<8|bufArr[0]; the result is a expected: 0x2002. to besure I read all 4 char and printed them. They were all present. Therefore: bufArr[3]=0x98 bufArr[2]=0x76 bufArr[1]= 0x54 bufArr[0]= 0x32. It must have something to do with the shift manupulation. It seems that only a shift of 8 is possible.

Comment: I assumed that it is only possible to use int (2 bytes) at once and I am using following code that works. I wonder if there is an way efficient way. unsigned long irCmd = (unsigned long) bufArr[3] << 24 | (unsigned long) bufArr[2] << 16;           irCmd |= (unsigned long) bufArr[1] << 8 | bufArr[0];